# How should I generate random numbers for a genetic algorithm?

Tags: c++, random, genetic-algorithm, number-theory

I'm writing a genetic algorithm to solve the Master Mind game. I've done lots of research on best approaches and it's incredibly important to have a diverse population. I'm trying to determine how to get really good random numbers in C++. I've done `srand(time(NULL))` at the start of my program to set the seed then I've simply used `rand()`. What I would like to know is how random is that really? Is it pretty good? Are there other better libraries for random numbers?

I know number theory and randomness is a very complicated subject; do you have any pointers in writing your own version of `rand()`?

Comment: If you have C++11, use [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: For a genetic algorithm, you don't need really good random numbers, `std::mt19937` will be fine.

Comment: See if one of these fits your needs: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: If you have C++11 you should use `std::mt19937` and probably `std::uniform_xxx_distribution`. If you don't have C++11 you should get it.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't know all those existed for C++11! I'll have to check but I think I have it. Those would be perfect!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For crypto, you need very strong properties on your random numbers. Much of the literature out there focusses on these sorts of requirements. A typical solution would be seeding iterated applications of SHA-256 using environmental noise (hard drive delays, network packets, mouse movements, RDRAND, HAVEGE, ...).

For Monte-Carlo simulations or AI applications, the randomness requirements are much lower indeed. In fact, very simple generators will be good enough. The most basic is the infamous Linear Congruential generator, which is considered a bit old-fashioned now, because the output patterns sometimes produce noticeable and unwanted sampling effects (in particular, some experimental studies done in the 70s and 80s are quite probably flawed because of this). These days, the Mersenne Twister is more popular, and is more than adequate for a computer game. It's available in the C++ standard library: see [std::mt19937](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine).

Comment: Thanks so much! That's very enlightening

Answer (score 2):

`rand()`'s randomness is really bad. It is a bog standard [LCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) and generally has bad randomness and bad quality of projection. If you are serious about quality of randomness for your application, you need to go with something better. Then it depends on whether you want to keep to the standard library, or not.

If you want to use standard library, go with `<random>` header and Mersenne Twister.

But, I would recommend to you to use [the PCG random family](http://www.pcg-random.org/) instead. Its fast, it has good quality and fixes most of mistakes of `<random>`.